# Kivy Label Text does not update

Tags: python, kivy

At the moment I am working on a calendar program with Kivy. I write this question for the second time, because the first time I could not fix the problem and the code was way to long with unnecessary lines for the actually problem.

My problem is in the print_appointment_to_label function. I wrote appointment_label.text = appointment_name_file_content at the end of the function, but the label text doesn't update only when I restart the program. If you wondering label_id_file_content stands for "1jal" which is the id for the label.

Thank you for your help Julius

Python:

```
#diable # diable multitouch
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock


class screenmanager(ScreenManager):
     pass


class PopupContent(FloatLayout):
    def store_appointment_name(self):
        appointment_name = self.ids.appointment_name.text
        with open("appointment_name_file","w") as appointment_name_file:
            appointment_name_file.write(appointment_name)

        Ja = JanuaryWindow()
        Ja.__init__()


class JanuaryWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(JanuaryWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.print_appointment_to_label, .5)

    def print_appointment_to_label(self,dt):
        with open("appointment_name_file", "r") as appointment_name_file:
            appointment_name_file_content = appointment_name_file.read()
        with open("label_id_file", "r") as label_id_file:
            label_id_file_content = label_id_file.read()


        appointment_label = self.ids[label_id_file_content]
        appointment_label.text = appointment_name_file_content



kv = Builder.load_file("Calendar-KIVY.kv")


class Calendar(App):
    def convert_button_id_in_label_id(self,button_id):
        with open("button_id_file","w") as button_id_file:
            button_id_file.write(button_id)

        with open("button_id_file", "r") as button_id_file:
            button_id_file_content = button_id_file.read()
            label_id = button_id_file_content.replace("b", "l")

        with open("label_id_file", "w") as label_id_file:
            label_id_file.write(label_id)

    def build_popup(self):
        contentp = PopupContent()
        popup = Popup(title="Make new appointment",content=contentp,size_hint=(None,None),size=(1500,1500))
        popup.open()


    def build(self):
        return kv


Calendar().run()
```

KV:

```
screenmanager:
    JanuaryWindow:



<PopupContent>:
    Label:
        text: "Enter your appointment name"
        size_hint: 0.4,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"y":0.6}
    TextInput:
        id: appointment_name
        size_hint: 0.4,0.06
        pos_hint: {"x":0.478,"y":0.615}
        multiline: False
    Button:
        text: "Create"
        size_hint: 0.8,0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1,"y":0.09}
        on_release:
            root.store_appointment_name()



<JanuaryWindow>:
    name : "JaW"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.38,"y":0.843}
            size_hint: 0.02,0.03
            text: "+"
            on_release:
                app.convert_button_id_in_label_id("1jab")
                app.build_popup()

        Label:
            id: 1jal
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3,"y":0.4}
            size_hint: 1,1
            text: ""
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the label text doesn't update only when I restart the program"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `store_appointment_name()` method does:

```
    Ja = JanuaryWindow()
    Ja.__init__()
```

These lines are creating a new instance of `JanuaryWindow` and calling its `__init__()` method. First, the newly created instance of `JanuaryWindow` is not the one that is in your App GUI, so any changes made to that instance, will have no effect on your GUI. By the way, the `__init__()` method is called when you do `JanuaryWindow()` so you should never need to call an `__init__()` method explicitly.

So, what you want to do is access the `JanuaryWindow` that is in your GUI. To do this, you can modify the `store_appointment_name()` method like this:

```
class PopupContent(FloatLayout):
    def store_appointment_name(self):
        appointment_name = self.ids.appointment_name.text
        with open("appointment_name_file","w") as appointment_name_file:
            appointment_name_file.write(appointment_name)

        Ja = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('JaW')
        Ja.print_appointment_to_label(0)
```

The above code uses the `App.get_running_app()` method to get a reference to the `App`. Then the `.root` accesses the `ScreenManager`, and the `get_screen('JaW')` gets the `JanuaryWindow` that is in your App GUI. The next line just calls the `print_appointment_to_label()` method